# Distribution of my shares

Tags: shares

What is  the safest way to distribute my shares between founders and investors?
I have tried talking to the co founders about it and they just want their shares and don't see the bigger picture, and with big investors coming I feel like my shares are the only ones being diluted.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking. Let's say there are 100 shares and there are 4 founders each have 25 shares. i.e. each of you now own 25% of company.

If you are looking for new investor to invest into your company, there are multiple ways this can be done.

1. All of you decide to sell 5 shares each to investor. Now 4 of you
   and investor own 20% of the company.
2. You can create 25 more shares and sell them to investor.
   All/Majority [depending on your formation clause]. The funds then
   belong to the company and can be deployed for growth. Now 4 of you
   and investor own 20% of the company.
3. You can ask all co-founders to invest more money in equal
   proportion. Thus have more funds, but same shareholding pattern.
4. You can sell 12 shares that you own to the investor. However this
   money is your's. If you choose to invest this back into the company,
   if you mean you are contributing more than what you are receiving in
   shares. This can only be done if you feel it is still beneficial to
   you [of course it would be much more beneficial to others as they
   are getting things free]

Ideally you should try to agree 1 or 2. Going down 4 is what you seem to suggest, best avoided. See what kind of exit clauses you have and if better off start something new alone or with different set of group.